# Difficulty in implementing cytoscape.js-qtip

Tags: qtip2, cytoscape.js

### Part I

I am finding it difficult to replicate the functionality of [cytoscape.js-qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip) in my code.

---

**Here is the JavaScript Code:**

```js
$(function()
{ 
    $('#cy').cytoscape
    ({
          style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
            .selector('node').css({'content': 'data(name)'})
            .selector('edge').css({'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'})
            .selector(':selected').css({'line-color': 'black'})
          elements: {
                nodes: [ 
                        { data: { id: '1', name: '1' } },
                        { data: { id: '2', name: '2' } },
                    ],
                edges: [{ data: { source: '1', target: '2' } }]
            },
          layout: { name: 'grid'},
          ready: function()
            {
                window.cy = this;
                cy.panzoom({});
                cy.cxtmenu
                ({  commands:[{ content: '<span class="fa fa-flash fa-2x"></span>',
                                select: function()  {console.log( this.id() );}
                              },
                              { content: '<span class="fa fa-star fa-li "></span>',
                                select: function(){ console.log( this.data('name') );}
                              },
                              { content: 'Text',
                                select: function(){ console.log( this.position() );}
                              }
                ]});
                cy.elements().qtip
                ({
                    content: function(){ return 'this is tool tip for ' + this.id() },
                    position: { my: 'top center',at: 'bottom center'},
                    style: {classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',tip: {width: 16,height: 8}}
                });

                cy.qtip
                ({
                    content: 'tool tip about the core of the layout',
                    position: { my: 'top center', at: 'bottom center'},
                    show: { cyBgOnly: true},
                    style: {classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',tip: {width: 16,height: 8}}
                });
            }
    }); 
});
```

---

***I have already gone through these threads:***

- [displaying qtip hover on outer nodes of cytoscape.js graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390633/displaying-qtip-hover-on-outer-nodes-of-cytoscape-js-graph)
- [how to use tooltip javascript library qtip.js together with cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019184/how-to-use-tooltip-javascript-libraryqtip-js-together-with-cytoscape-js)
- [how to add tooltip on mouseover event on nodes in graph with cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993149/how-to-add-tooltip-on-mouseover-event-on-nodes-in-graph-with-cytoscape-js)
- [referencing cytoscape elements from external code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851698/referencing-cytoscape-elements-from-external-code)
- [cytoscape.js force-directed layouts and node placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109168/cytoscape-js-force-directed-layouts-and-node-placement)

  ---

**Errors shown in Browser Console:**

> **TypeError:** qtip.$domEle.qtip is not a function
>
> **File     :** [cytoscape.js-qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip)
>
> **Line     :** 88
>
> **Col      :** 1
>
> **Code     :** qtip.$domEle.qtip( opts );

---

### Part II

Also when I am trying the example provided [over here](http://jsbin.com/gist/546dd8ca4872cc87106a?js,output), I see no qtip on tapping.

**Note:** *I tried on both Mozilla Firefox & Google Chrome*.

And encountered the following Errors in the Browser Console:

> - **Mozilla Firefox**
>
>   - **GET** http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js
>
>     - [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 0ms]
>   - **TypeError:** qtip.$domEle.qtip is not a function
>   - **File     :** [cytoscape.js-qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip)
>   - **Line     :** 97
>   - **Col      :** 6
> - **Google Chrome:**
>
>   - **GET** https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/70964f0306e770837dbe2b81197c12fdc7804e38/cytoscape-qtip.js  runner-3.25.19.min.js:1
>   - **TypeError:** Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'
>
>     - **at**  HTMLDocument. (http://null.jsbin.com/runner:27:12)
>     - **at**  j (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:2:27244)
>     - **at**  Object.k.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:2:28057)
>     - **at**  Function.m.extend.ready (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:2:29891)
>     - **at**  HTMLDocument.J (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:2:30257) runner-3.25.19.min.js:1
>   - **Uncaught TypeError:** Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip' runner:27
>
>     - (anonymous function) runner:27
>     - j
>     - k.fireWith
>     - m.extend.ready

Comment: Have you tried the example that comes with the extension?

Comment: Yes Sir. 
I have tried examples for both **qtip** as well as for **ctxtmenu** - they work fine. 
In fact it works absolutely fine when I merged the two examples to get the two functionality i.e ___qtip and the ctxtmenu___ together. But when I tried implementing the same on the above code, it does not work. I apologize if my issue is silly. I am new to this. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer to Part I

> The actual mistake was in the ***order of importing*** of JavaScript within the **HTML** file.

---

**Mistake:**

```
<script src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

---

**Correction:**

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

---

**Conclusion:**

> **Correct Order of importing**
>
> 1. jquery-2.0.3.js
> 2. jquery.qtip.js

---

**Reason:**

> The order of **importing/ loading** is important as **jquery.qtip.js** is dependent on **jquery-2.0.3.js**.

---

**For better understanding:**

> **Read :** [cytoscape.js-qtip#description](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip#description)

---