# How to include Cytoscape.js Extension Cytoscape-qtip into an Ember App

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, cytoscape.js

I would like to use the Cytoscape extension `cytoscape-qtip` in a component of my Ember app which already uses Cytoscape.js as a dependency to draw a graph.

### Successful Setup of Cytoscape.js

Cytoscape.js itself is already successfully hooked into Ember by installing it via bower `bower install cytoscape` and importing it via ember-cli-build.js:

*in my-ember-app/ember-cli-build.js:*

```
// in my-ember-app/ember-cli-build.js
// ....
app.import('bower_components/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.js');
return app.toTree();
```

In my `cytoscape-graph` component I can then use the `cytoscape` global variable out of the box:

*in my-ember-app/app/components/cytoscape-graph.js:*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
didInsertElement(){
  let container = this.$();
 // ...
 var cy = cytoscape({
   container: container,
 // ... styles, layout, element selection
 }); // this cytoscape instance renders fine!
```

Accessing the global `cytoscape` works fine with this approach.

---

### Analogue Setup of Cytoscape-Qtip doesn't work

Although, when I install `cytoscape-qtip` via bower, import the dependency similar to `cytoscape` into my app in `ember-cli-build.js` like so:

*in my-ember-app/ember-cli-build.js:*

```
// ...
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  // ;....
  });
  // ....
  app.import('bower_components/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.js');
  app.import('bower_components/cytoscape-qtip/cytoscape-qtip.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

and try to use the `qtip` method in my `cytoscape-graph` component:

*in my-ember-app/app/components/cytoscape-graph.js:*

```
// ....
didInsertElement(){
  // ....
  cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(event) {
    var node = event.cyTarget;
    node.qtip({
        content: 'hello',
        show: {
            event: event.type,
            ready: true
        },
        hide: {
            event: 'mouseout unfocus'
        }
    }, event);
  });
```

I will get the following console error once the mouseover event on any graph node is triggered:

`Uncaught TypeError: qtip.$domEle.qtip is not a function(…)` indicating that qtip itself is not defined in my component yet. [A similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672437/difficulty-in-implementing-cytoscape-js-qtip) didn't help me with my issue, as the person asking there had issues with `jquery` being loaded in the correct order. In my case `jquery` is already included in my app and working fine.

---

How do I include the `cytoscape-qtip` extension in my Ember app to be able to use `qtip` in my component?

Comment: Just to be sure, you've called `app.import` in the right order?

Comment: Do you mean the right order being: 1. load cytoscape, 2. load cytoscape-qtip? I have included the order of ``app.import``s in my current ember-cli-build.js file up ahead in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the instructions for registering the extension and its dependencies exactly as specified in the readme:

For CommonJS (e.g. npm+browserify or npm+webpack):

```
var cytoscape = require('cytoscape');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var cyqtip = require('cytoscape-qtip');

cyqtip( cytoscape, jquery ); // register extension
```

For ES6 style (any tooling that supports ES6):

```
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import cyqtip from 'cytoscape-qtip';

cyqtip( cytoscape, jquery ); // register extension
```

The lines are pretty much identical either way.

Qtip must be registered to jQuery, so you'll probably have to expose jQuery globally first:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('qtip');
```

See also https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/pull/810

Comment: I have problems importing the cyqtip module from the cytoscape-qtip package: `loader.js:219 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `cytoscape-qtip` imported from 'my-ember-app/components/cytoscape-graph'` Do I need to follow any additional steps to expose the module  properly so I can import it in my component?

Comment: Ember.js components are based on ES6 modules and use the `import` syntax to load modules. Therefore I tried the setup you described for the ES6 style of module loading in your answer as follows: `import cyqtip from 'cytoscape-qtip'; cyqtip( cytoscape, jQuery );` Global variables defined in vendor libraries are implicitly defined and available in my Ember component. Therefore I can confirm the definition of jQuery and cytoscape in the component by a simple `console.log(jQuery); console.log(cytoscape);` which returns the function in the console without any errors.

Comment: Extensions aren't going to expose anything globally, nor should they.  You'll have to configure your module loader.  If you use npm and Webpack or Browserify, that's always automatic.  If you use bower, you'll have to figure out how Ember handles non-global packages and/or package lookup.  Unless Ember only works with bower, you may want to consider using npm instead.  Npm is far better than bower.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var node = event.cyTarget;
                                                       node.qtip({
                                                           content: 'hello:',
                                                           position: {
                                                               my: 'top center',
                                                               at: 'bottom center',
                                                               adjust: {
                                                                   method: 'shift'
                                                               },
                                                               viewport: true
                                                           },

                                                           show: {
                                                               event: 'mouseover'
                                                           },

                                                           hide: {
                                                               event: 'mouseout unfocus'
                                                           },

                                                           style: {
                                                               classes: 'qtip-bootstrap qtip-filters',
                                                               tip: {
                                                                   width: 16,
                                                                   height: 8
                                                               }
                                                           },


                                                       });
```

Comment: 1. Properly format your code. 2. Explain what this code does and how/why it solves problem in question.